# Visual Studio: show all special characters in a string

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, special-characters

While debugging, Visual Studio does not show some special characters in a string. Most of you are familiar with the way notepad++ displays special characters (copied from another post):
[image]

To be a bit more specific, my string contains the record separator with character code 30. Notepad++ shows it like `[RS]`. Visual Studio does not show it at all. So a string like `hello[RS]stackoverflow[RS]1[RS]2` becomes `hellostackoverflow12`. Even worse, if a string ends with "invisible" characters, there is no way to notice this, because the string still looks sensible. I want to be able to see all characters in debug mode, while hovering over strings, and in the watch window.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular-expressions to find out special-characters-in-a-string

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "Th!s $tri^g c@n$ist $pecial ch@rs";
    Match match = Regex.Match(str, "[^a-z0-9]",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        string key = match.Value;
        Console.Write(key);
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```